# How do I format and put images in an email from my app?

Tags: iphone, image, email, format

There have been some older posts about this with very complicated answers.  I was wonder if there is a simple way to take an image that is in your project and put it in an email, composed your app but sent through the mail program.

I also don't know how to format it.  If I put \n the mail program is never opened.

Here is what does work:

```
            NSString *url = [NSString stringWithString: @"mailto:?&subject=Hello%20There!&body=Really%20Cool.%20Check%20this%20out!"];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

And I would like to add an image and make it look nice, with newlines.  Could someone help me out here?

Thanks!
R

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, image as attachment with a mail compose view, or inline as HTML, which means you'd have to upload the app's images somewhere accessible with a permalink or fixed URL. Even if you can form a URL with a local path, the email recipient doesn't receive mail using your app, so it's sandboxed away from the world.

If you generate the pictures in the app it's not easier than a mail compose view, but if uploading them is okay it's dead easy.

I solved it today by uploading optimized and smaller jpg versions of the png images with FTP and linking to it with `<b><img src="http://blah.etc.org/myfolder/mypic.jpg" /></b>`. The `<b>` tags were needed to "trick" openURL into not stripping the image back in SDK 3.0, they might not be needed now.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use MFMailComposeViewController to send an attachment.

Attach an image that is part of your app (in the same directory) to an email like this:

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; 
    [picker setSubject:@"My Image Is Attached"];

//other mail settings here

//now add your attachment
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *whereToFindFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage.png"];
            NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:whereToFindFile];
            NSData *imageData1 = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:appFile] autorelease]; 
            [picker addAttachmentData:imageData1 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myImage"];
```

Comment: I was trying to do it within the email, not as an attachment.  I got it finally. Thanks though.  I am sure this works too!

Comment: @Rossi please share the code you used to embed the image in the email and not as an attachment!